# How can I capture the group catch by starts in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python2.7 and I want to capture all module names by import "os", "ma"
so i use regular expresson from the `re` module to do this. I created a test string:

```
testString = "import os, math, string"
```

Here I'm using regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^import\s+(\w,\s*)*(\w+)")
pattern.findall(testString)
```

This gives me `[('math,','string')]`, but no `os`, so I tried to use the search method.

```
p.search(a).groups()
```

This gives me the same result as with findall.

```
p.search(a).group(0)
```

Gives me `'import os, math, string'`

How can i get the module name 'os' by regular expression?

Comment: Maybe `testString[7:].split(", ")` is enough? See https://ideone.com/mdRUBa

Comment: Current output is `[('', 'os')]`, [live code](http://ideone.com/fvAjNC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testString = "import os, math, string"
re.findall(r"\b(\w+)(?:,|$)", testString)
```

The output is:

```
['os', 'math', 'string']
```

Comment: i got it in python doc.thanks very much.but @Igor Chubin understand what i meant. i need repeated captures.

Answer (score 1):

The `import os, math, string` string seems to start with `import`, so, all you need is to check whether the string starts with `import`, and then remove it and split with `,`:

```
testString = "import os, math, string"
if testString.startswith("import "):
    print(testString[7:].split(', '))
# = > ['os', 'math', 'string']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Gr9ixe)

If the spaces are used inconsistently between the commas and packages, use

```
[x.strip() for x in testString[7:].split(',')]
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/N4gRVI)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: use `\w+` instead of `\w`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^import\s+(\w+,\s*)*(\w+)")
```

But the main problem is: `re` module doesn't support repeated captures (`regex` supports it)

```
>>> m = regex.match("^import\s+(\w+,\s*)*(\w+)", testString)
>>> m.captures(1)
['os, ', 'math, ']
```

If you want to use `regex`, you should install it first.
It is not a part of standard library.

But it would be better to use `findall` in this case, like @akash_karothiya suggests.

Answer (score 0):

[jcxu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913868/how-can-i-capture-the-group-catch-by-starts-in-python/38921616#38921616) is pretty nice, here is another one.

```
testString = "import os, math, string"
re.search(r"(?!import)\s(\w.+)", testString).group(1).split(', ')
```

or shorter

```
re.findall(r"(?!import)\s(\w.+)", testString)
```